# Why does IfError return error?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a wrapper for the INDEX/MATCH lookup method (which is faster/better than the regular VLOOKUP method) by creating a custom function and loading it afterwards as an add-in.

So far so good, but my desired behavior is that, when the value to be looked up is not found, it should return blank ("") and not #VALUE!. So I am trying to use the IfError WorksheetFunction in order to achieve this the same way I would on an Excel sheet:

```
Function FastLookup(parLookupKey As Variant, parLookupRange As Range, parReturnRange As Range) As Variant

    FastLookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(parReturnRange, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(parLookupKey, parLookupRange, 0)), "")

End Function
```

Again, this still returns #VALUE! if a value is not found on the parLookupRange range.

Needless to say, if I use =IFERROR(FastLookup(H6,E3:E6,F3:F6),"") directly on the Excel sheet, it works.

Any ideas on how to make the VBA version of IfError work?

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` causes a *VBA run-time error* if there's no match found - you cannot trap that type of error with `IfError` but instead need to use VBA error handling as shown in @scott craner's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the error never makes it past the MATCH function in vba. As soon as that throws an error the code will stop.

Use this instead:

```
Function FastLookup(parLookupKey As Variant, parLookupRange As Range, parReturnRange As Range) As Variant

    Dim t As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    t = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(parLookupKey, parLookupRange, 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If t > 0 Then
        FastLookup = parReturnRange(t)
    Else
        FastLookup = ""
    End If

End Function
```

We now capture the error and ignore it.  Then we test for it and return the correct value.

Comment: This works great and I understand why it failed before. Thanks. But why doesn't nested IfError work? (i.e., wrap the inner Match function in an IfError function, then wrap the outside Index function with another IfError function)?

Comment: Did you see @TimWilliams comment.  The worksheet function IFERROR will not capture the error.  The error is thrown by vba and it stops looking at the rest of the formula as soon as it finds the error and exits the function without testing the next step in the formula. So we need to isolate the one part and tell vba to skip it if it throws an error. then test for that error.

Comment: No, I did not see that comment, the only post I saw/see is yours. Thanks a lot for your help and feedback!